# How to get current path with query string using Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

The page url is something like `/people?search=name`
while I used `current_path` method of capybara it returned `/people` only.

```
current_path.should == people_path(:search => 'name')
```

But it fails saying

```
expected: "/people?search=name"
got: "/people"
```

How we can make it pass? Is there is any way to do this?

Comment: `"/people?search=name"` [is not a path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Generic_syntax). `"/people"` is a path

Answer (score 236, accepted):

I've updated this answer to reflect modern conventions in capybara. I think this is ideal since this is the accepted answer, and what many people are being referred to when looking for a solution. With that said, the correct way to check the current path is to use the `has_current_path?` matcher provided by Capybara, as documented here: [Click Here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/SessionMatchers#has_current_path%3F-instance_method)

Example usage:

```
expect(page).to have_current_path(people_path(search: 'name'))
```

As you can see in the documentation, other options are available. If the current page is `/people?search=name` but you only care that it's on the `/people` page regardless of the param, you can send the `only_path` option:

```
expect(page).to have_current_path(people_path, only_path: true)
```

Additionally, if you want to compare the entire URL:

```
expect(page).to have_current_path(people_url, url: true)
```

Credit to Tom Walpole for pointing out this method.

Comment: I'll probably need this syntax very soon, I'm writing tests for a legacy application. Using `current_path.should ==` is working for now (though I need to add a trailing forward-slash as a string). I'm thanking you in advance for code I'll likely need.

Comment: `URI.parse(current_url).request_uri` is more succinct. See @Lasse Bunk's answer.

Comment: As of Capybara 2.5, this is no longer the best answer. See @tom-walpole's answer below.

Comment: Since the asker is unlikely to change the accepted answer, I've updated the answer to reflect modern times. This should be more helpful to new users looking for a solution and seeing the first answer. Thanks @OddityOverseer for pointing it out

Comment: For new Capybara versions use `ignore_query: true` instead of `only_path: true`

Answer (score 95):

I replaced the _path method with _url to achieve comparing the full urls with parameters.

```
current_url.should == people_url(:search => 'name')
```

Comment: How did you deal with the host part?

Comment: You can also use `current_path` in newer versions of Capybara and match it against `people_path(...)`

Comment: When I dont have named path... I have only /users/register... then how I should use it?

Comment: What if it's happening on a render, so that the URL is different from the html page?

Answer (score 57):

Just updating this question for modern times.  The current best practice for checking current_paths when using Capybara 2.5+ is to use the current_path matcher, which will use Capybaras waiting behavior to check the path.  If wanting to check against the request_uri (path and query string)

```
expect(page).to have_current_path(people_path(:search => 'name'))
```

If only wanting the path part (ignoring the query string)

```
expect(page).to have_current_path(people_path, only_path: true) # Capybara < 2.16
expect(page).to have_current_path(people_path, ignore_query: true) # Capybara >= 2.16
```

If wanting to match the full url

```
expect(page).to have_current_path(people_url, url: true) # Capybara < 2.16
expect(page).to have_current_path(people_url) # Capybara >= 2.16
```

the matcher will take a string which is compared with == or a regex to match against

```
expect(page).to have_current_path(/search=name/)
```

Comment: in these modern times this should be marked as *the* answer. This will safe a lot of vague timing issues, thanks!

Comment: @Vanuan rspec has been deprecating the `should` syntax. You should strive to use `expect().to` in your specs going forward.

Comment: `only_path: true` is now `ignore_query: true`

Answer (score 20):

I know an answer has been selected, but I just wanted to give an alternative solution. So:

To get the path and querystring, like `request.fullpath` in Rails, you can do:

```
URI.parse(current_url).request_uri.should == people_path(:search => 'name')
```

You can also do a helper method in your test class (like `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest`) like this (which is what I did):

```
def current_fullpath
  URI.parse(current_url).request_uri
end
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: as Tinynumberes mentioned, this fails for URLs with port number. Keeping it here in case anyone else has the same brilliant idea.

```
current_url[current_host.size..-1]
```

golfs exactly as well (35 chars) as `URI.parse(current_url).request_uri`, but is potentially faster because there is no explicit URI parsing involved.

I have made a pull request to add this to Capybara at: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/pull/1405

Comment: This doesn't work if the `current_url` might contain a port number.  E.g. given a `current_url` of `http://foo.com:8888/some/path`, `current_url[current_host.size..-1]` will equal `:8888/some/path`.

Also, behind the scenes `current_host` does the same sort of `URI.parse` logic that @nzifnab recommended in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Beware that author mentioned [in this comment](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/pull/1405#issuecomment-703314828).
That usage of `current_url` can lead to flaky tests.