# capybara click_link with question mark parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to make a test in rails using Rspec + Capybara + FactoryGirl.

In my page the user can click a link that is generated like this:

```
<a href="<%= email_path(emails: booking.dummy_user.email) %>" title="<%= t(".send_email") %>" id="send_email_dummy_<%= booking.dummy_user.id %>" >
    <span class="icon-envelope"></span>
</a>
```

In my test I'm doing :

```
click_link "send_email_dummy_" + dummy_user.id.to_s
current_path.should eq(email_path(locale: "en", emails: dummy_user.email))
```

However instead of the test passing it is returning:

```
expected: "/en/email?emails=student%40email.com"
     got: "/en/email"
```

I printed the page generated by the test and the link is correctly generated:

```
<a href="/en/email?emails=student%40email.com" title="Send Email" id="send_email_dummy_1" >
    <span class="icon-envelope"></span>
</a>
```

Anyone has any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: The problem is with a current_path
Here is your solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228371/how-to-get-current-path-with-query-string-using-capybara

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `eq` with current_path or current_url in Capybara, you'll regret it as soon as you start using a driver that supports JS and things become asynchronous.  Instead use the `have_current_path` matcher

```
page.should have_current_path(email_path(locale: "en", emails: dummy_user.email))
```

by default that will include the path with query parameters in the match (which you want in your case).  If you don't want them included you can do

```
page.should have_current_path(email_path(locale: "en", emails: dummy_user.email), only_path: true)
```

and if you want to compare the whole url you can do

```
page.should have_current_path(email_path(locale: "en", emails: dummy_user.email), url: true)
```